# How to get each of objects in list on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of questions. 
And I have a html, f.e., . Each click, changes html ".title" with a next question from objects.
Click on button, I get: "Is it good to be me?",
next click, I get: "Who is the best man?" and so on...

```js
var questions = {
 first: "Is it good to be me?",
 second: "Who is the best man?",
 third: "Do you believe?",
 fourth: "Are you sexy?"
};
var txt = "";
var x;

for(x in questions) {
 txt += questions[x] + "<br>";
  console.log(txt)
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Can you add complete HTML & expected HTML.

Comment: Why an object? If order is important, you should better use an array for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: Jonathan, so the better thing is to use loop for... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array` instead of `object`.

```js
var questions = [
    "Is it good to be me?",
    "Who is the best man?",
    "Do you believe?",
    "Are you sexy?"
];

var index = 0;
$("button").click(function(){
    $("div").text(questions[index]);
    index++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<br/>
<button>Get question</button>
```

To getting index of question, use `index` variable. Also you can use `data-index` attribute to do this.

Comment: so there is no need in looping? 8(

Comment: @NeedHate No, you can get target question using `index` variable like `questions[index]`.

Comment: Ok, gonna use your advice.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
for(x in questions) {
    txt += questions[x] + "\n";
}
console.log(txt)
```